# dynamic query filter with SQLalchemy operators

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a list : `scope_list = ['prd1 rls1', ' prd1 rls1 rls3 rls2']`

I would like to create a filter based on `scope_list` that in SQL would look like :

```
(product=prd1 AND `release` in (rls1)) OR (product=prd1 AND release in (rls1 ,rls3, rls2))
```

Knowing that the number of values in `scope_list` varies and that I can't previously know it. This is why I would like to manage the filter dynamically from `scope_list`.

In SQL Alchemy I guess I should do something like this :

```
session.query(my_table).filter(or_(and_(my_table.product==%s,mytable.release.in_(%s))) for element.split() in scope_list)
```

I'm just starting to learn SQL Alchemy, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `or_` and `and_` can take variable number of positional arguments, so if you build a list you can pass it in as position arguments with `or_(*or_args)`.

```
# First I split each term in the scope list.
scope_list = [term.split() for term in scope_list]
# Then the query is built.
or_args = [and_(
    my_table.product == scope[0], 
    my_table.release.in_(scope[1:])) for scope in scope_list]
results = session.query(my_table).filter(or_(*or_args)).all()
```